# Custom Formula Field on custom object has disappeared from page layout

Tags: custom-object, formula-field

The custom formula field that I created has disappeared from my page layout. All of the field security settings have been ticked, the right profiles are being used... I can't figure it out.

Image 1: shows the page layout when I'm in 'setup' -> 'create' -> 'Objects' -> 'Health Scores'('HS' is my custom object) -> 'page layouts'. As you can see the formula scores are there, but when I click into the account, see image 2.

Image 2: Is when I'm on the account and clicking into the 'Health Score' object. The fields disappear... does anyone have any explanation?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 2):

Formula fields do not appear on edit screens unless in LEX. See also:

> ## [Formula fields should show on new/edit page](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Zpy4AAC)
>
> > #### Latest Comment from Salesforce
> >
> > This idea will be delivered in Spring '16 in the new Lightning Experience. On a broader level, we have taken steps to unify the fields a user sees in normal Detail Pages and New/Edit pages so that formula fields, summary rollups, embedded Visualforce and Custom Links (on Accounts, Contacts, Leads) will be visible on New/Edit pages for a user's reference.

Answer (score 2):

Formula fields will be visible in the detail page after saving the record.
In case of Edit mode those are not visible.